# Storing MySQL values as integers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two database tables that I am using to create a Twitter-style following system.

```
sh_subscriptions
    => id
    => user_id
    => feed_id

sh_feeds
    => id
    => item
    => shop_name
    => feed_id
```

The problem with storing `feed_id` rather than `shop_name` in `sh_subscriptions` is that it requires a lot of table joining:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$user_id = $id['id'];
$shop_name = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['shop_name']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN sh_feeds f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id WHERE s.user_id = $user_id AND f.shop_name = '$shop_name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $query2 = "DELETE FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN sh_feeds f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id WHERE s.user_id = $user_id AND f.shop_name = '$shop_name'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}

else
{
    // insert the row instead
}
```

(I know there's an error somewhere in the if statement, but I'll worry about that later.)

If I were to replace `feed_id` with `shop_name`, I would be able to replace line 5 with this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions WHERE user_id = $user_id AND shop_name = '$shop_name'";
```

My question is: is it always preferable to store MySQL values as integers where possible, or in a situation like this, would it be faster to have `sh_subscriptions` contain `shop_name` rather than `feed_id`?

Comment: What if the shop_name changes?

Comment: @DanBracuk Is that the only reason to keep feed_id?

Comment: What if two feeds have the same shop_name but different items?

Comment: EVERY row in a database shoulb be identifiable by a single unique value.
Even if you have a aggregation table consisting of just two foreign key it is prefered to have another column containing a primary key, even if the combination of the foreign keys could be used as one.
You keep your data portable that way an it is easier to query those data from any point of the application.
Also integers are very easy to validate. String on the other hand are kind of hard, because you need to specify exactly what you want in them and what not.

Comment: @func0der, the design principle you mention (always provide a surrogate primary key) simply isn't valid when using entity-relationship style database design.

Comment: @OllieJones Can you explain me, why that is so?
I know there is an overhead there, by using my method, but especially if you store some additional data to an association it is more than useful to have a primary key for it.

Comment: We're talking about a join table here: an n:n relationship between rows of two other tables. Each of these relationships is unambiguously identified by a pair of values (m,n). It makes no logical sense to have two rows in the join table with the same pair of values. Primary keys serve two purposes in RDM systems: rapid access and uniqueness. Therefore a compound of the two id columns can serve both purposes. If you add a separate id column you must also create a unique key on the two id numbers, or risk having duplicates. This extra id column causes problems and solves none.

Comment: What if you are joining about 10 relations in one table with speaking column names and additional data. That query would be a pain in the ass to write with all the conditions just to address a field in that join table.
I know there has to be assurance that the foreign key combination does not double in the table, but for addressing just the data bound to the association I think it is easier to have the additional identifier there.
Maybe this is just a personal thing, but it seems not invalid to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sh_subscriptions table is actually a many-to-many join table that relates users to feeds. This is considered a fine way to design database schemas.

Your basic concept is this: you have a collection of users and a collection of feeds. Each user can subscribe to zero or more feeds, and each feed can have zero or more subscribers.

To enter a subscription you create a row in the sh_subscriptions table. To cancel it you delete the row.

You say there's "a lot of table joining." With respect, this is not a lot of table joining. MySQL is made for this kind of joining, and it will work well.

I have some suggestions about your sh_subscriptions table.

1. get rid of the `id` column. Instead make the user_id and feed_id columns into a composite primary key. That way you will automatically prevent duplicate subscriptions.
2. add an `active` column ... a short integer ... to the table. When it is set to a value of `1` your suscription is active. That way you can cancel a subscription by setting `active` to 0.
3. you might also add a `subscribed_date` column if you care about that.
4. create two compound non unique indexes `(active,user_id,feed_id)` and `(active,feed_id,userId)` on the table. These will greatly accelerate queries that join tables like this.

Query fragment:

```
   FROM sh_feed f
   JOIN sh_subscription s ON (f.feed_id = s.feed_id AND s.active = 1)
   JOIN sh_users u ON (s.user_id = u.user_id)
  WHERE f.shop_name = 'Joe the Plumber'
```

If you get to the point where you have hundreds of millions of users or feeds, you may need to consider denormalizing this table.. that is, for example, relocating the shop name text so it's in the sh_subscriptions table. But not now.

*Edit* I am proposing multiple *compound covering indexes*. If you're joining feeds to users, for example, MySQL starts satisfying your query by determining the row in sh_feeds that matches your selection.

It then determines the feed_id, and random-accesses your compound index on feed_id.  Then, it needs to look up all the user_id values for that feed_id.  It can do that by scanning the index from the point where it random-accessed it, without referring back to the table. This is very fast indeed. It's called a *covering index*.

The other covering index deals with queries that start with a known user and proceed to look up the feeds. The order of columns in indexes matters: random access can only start with the first (leftmost) column of the index.

The trick to understand is that these indexes are both randomly accessible and sequentially scannable.

*one other note* If you only have two columns in the join table, one of your covering indexes is also your primary key, and the other contains the columns in the reverse order from the primary key. You don't need any duplicate indexes.

Comment: As stated here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472191/storing-mysql-values-as-integers#comment35988558_23472191), I would not drop the `id` column in `sh_subscriptions`.

Comment: @func0der, if the original questioner adopts the entity-relationship style of database design I am suggesting here, his join tables (also known as many-to-many relationship tables) simply do not need a surrogate primary key like the id key. That key confuses the issue of data integrity. It adds unnecessary overhead to table maintenance and can add overhead to queries.  You are right that some primary key is better than no primary key. But (user_id, feed_id) is a perfectly good primary key.

Comment: Thanks very much for this comprehensive response. A couple of questions: 1) are you suggesting the `active` column as a replacement for adding and deleting database fields? If so, what's the benefit of knowing that a user was once subscribed to a feed but now isn't (which would be the case if `active` was equal to 0)? 2) Why do you need *two* compound non unique indexes?

Comment: `active` is no substitute for INSERTing rows into the subscription table. But I do propose it as a substitute for DELETEing rows. If you are sure you never need to know about a historical subscription, then go ahead and DELETE. It's a design preference.